# Document Version Calculated Column problem in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online

I´ve added a calculated column (Name: CalculatedVersion) in SharePoint Online (Spanish) using this formula:

=Versión

When browsing to default Document Library View i see that CalculatedVersion value is ok.

When adding a new Document, CalculatedVersion value is 0.

To correct this problem the workaround i´ve found is go to the CalculatedVersion column edit form, and reaccept the formula.

Now the value is correct.

I´ve tried changing version field name from "versión" to "version" with no luck.

This is the formula value from SharePoint Designer, =_UIVersionString . It´s ok!!!

Any ideas? When other fields are used, this problem does not occur.
Best regards.

Comment: A `0` for that value seems to make sense to me, since you haven't actually created an item until you hit submit on the new item form. After you submit the item, then go back and view the item in the list, has it's version number changed? I can't remember, but you may not get version 1 until after you do the first check-in also.

Comment: Sharepoint internal Version column is working ok. After submitting the item, the item version changed to 1.0 but my calculated column value is still 0. Re-accepting the formula is the only way i´ve found to update this value.

Comment: When you create/edit your Calculated Column, Version is **not** listed as an available column.
Same goes for the [ID] field, which you can enter in a Calculated Column, but does not function as wanted/expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I been able to solve this problem creating a receiver event handler:

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        string internalName = properties.ListItem.Fields["VersionString"].InternalName;

        //Turn off event firing during item update
        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        item[internalName] = item["_UIVersion"];
        item.Update();

        //Turn back on event firing
        base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
    }


    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        string internalName = properties.ListItem.Fields["VersionString"].InternalName;

        //Turn off event firing during item update
        base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

        SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
        item[internalName] = item["Versión"];

        item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();

        //Turn back on event firing
        base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a good amount of looking between me and another developer, it seems that Calculated Columns will not work for Version.  This was the case in SharePoint 2010 and appears to still be the case with Office365.

The options are to create an event receive as suggested above or to create a workflow that copies the Version field value to whatever custom column field that you like.  We setup a workflow for our needs in SP2010.  We'll have to do the same in O365.